# The push notification Registration tab location in IBM Bluemix

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I tried the following link for push notification using IBM Bluemix:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-cordova-push-app/#N101D0

However,  I am stuck on step 6.
To verify that the device was registered, go to the Bluemix console. Click the Push service for your application and navigate to the Registrations tab. You can see your device within the list. Notice that the Consumer ID matches the one you gave when registering the device.

However, I cannot find the Registration tab in my IBM Bluemix console.

Also, I cannot find the references for the following step:

Open the IBM Bluemix console and click your application. Under Development Services, click the service for Mobile Application Security:

Please help me find the location of Registration tab and Mobile Application Security in IBM Blumix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial is outdated and is referencing deprecated services which is why you're hitting those issues (the registrations tab has been removed as you note for example).

Please take a look at https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush to see how to use the new IBM Push Notifications service with Cordova as well as https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/index.html for overall information regarding the new IBM Push Notifications service.

Thank you for bringing the deprecated doc to our attention, I'll look into updating it to make it clear it is referencing deprecated services and the old Bluemix UI.

Comment: its working.. how can i implement this one to my hybrid application done in mobilefirst